# Can we say which clustering model is good by just simply comparing silhouette score?

Tags: clustering, pca

I'm working on a dataset which has 13 features and in order to achieve more than 80% explained variance through PCA, I chose 5 number of PCs. With those 5 PCs, I want to know which clustering algorithm works best so I want to apply every single clustering algorithm(kmeans, dbscan, spectral clustering...) and pick one which gives the highest silhouette score.

But there are some concerns regarding to this approach. One says that I should not solely consider the magnitude of silhouette score but literally see the distribution of data points in order to rationally cluster the data. Is it true? Is there any problem in my approach? If so, how can I visualize my data where only 2 or 3 PCs just explain 30-40% of my whole data?